# Placement not working in Angular UI datepicker

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/waH311jBlTMiwKTkM7XY?p=preview) I have an Angular UI datepicker that shows up below the input field. I want the calendar to be displayed on top of the field, so I tried with  `popup-placement="top-left"` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"
           datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" popup-placement="top-left" 
           datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
  </p>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.opened = false;

    $scope.dateOptions = {
       showWeeks: false
    };


    $scope.open1 = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = true;
      };


});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`popup-placement` directive does not exist on `ui-bootstrap` version 0.13.
it seems like it's only been added since version `1.2.0`.

Best thing would be to update your version, previous versions don't seem to support that option (you can always manipulate the `css` but that's quite dangerous).

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GpFbD3u07PBhOnLG7SW6?p=preview) with updated `ui-bootstrap` and `angular` versions.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved your problem and  created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PsCjLBzWk5QRHO2EIPIe?p=preview.

your ui-bootstrap version should be updated.

you need to updated your angularjs version 1.5.0, ui-bootstrap version 1.2.4, bootstrap 3.3.6, and then add `uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"` to your datepicker input element.

Comment: Yes, you can try it!

Comment: i don't think my answer is the same to your one. I posted this answer which only marks my try to solve this problem!